# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00765C2C в Project7.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00B00000., произошло

Tags: c++, c

я только начал изучать си и ничего ещё не понимаю поэтому не мог бы кто подсказать как эта ошибка решается и из-за чего она вообще возникла?
код

```
#include "string.h" #include "stdio.h"#include <clocale>#include "conio.h"#include <stdlib.h>#include <errno.h>#include <cstdio>#include "Header.h"#include <malloc.h>int main(){
char o = '*';
//char p = '?';
int h;
int u = 0;
int *b;
char m[100];
char pot[100];
char ot[100];
int t = 0;
int at = 0;
char dot[100];
char ms[100];
printf_s("enter text:");
int gg = 5;
char* l;
//scanf("%s",m,20);
gets_s(m);
printf_s(m);
int rr = strlen(m)-1;
printf_s("enter word mask:");
gets_s(pot, 100);
printf_s("enter word for change:");
gets_s(ot, 100);
char rtf[100];
char rtp[100];
char yyy = pot[0];
int hh = 0;
for (int l = 0; l < strlen(m) || t <= strlen(pot); l++) {
    //int u;
    //m =malloc(_MAX_PATH);
    //int pp=0;
    //int l = 0;
    //int k = reinterpret_cast<int>(l);
    int k = l;
    char ll = m[k];
    char yy = pot[t];
    at = 0;
    //t = t++;
    if (ll == yy && at > 0 && t <= strlen(pot)) {
        hh = hh + 1;
        at = at + 1;
        t = t++;
        //ms[hh] = ll;
    }
    else if (yy == o)
    {
        hh = hh + 1;
        at = at + 1;
        //ms[hh] = ll;
    }
    else
    {
        at = 0;
    }
    if (t > strlen(pot))
    {
        //int pp = u+at+2;
        strcpy_s(rtp, &m[k]);
        int pp = rr - k + t;
        int jj = pp;
        //strcpy_s(rtp, &rtp[jj]);
        memset(rtp, 0, strlen(rtp));
    }
    if (ll == yyy) {
        int cc = k - t;
        strcpy(rtf, m);//
        int hh = 0;
        int u = k;
        memset(rtf, 0, strlen(rtf));
        at = at + 1;
        //ms[hh] = ll;
    }
}
strncpy(dot, rtf,t);
strcat(dot,ot);
strcat(dot,rtp);
//puts(m);
printf_s("%s", dot);
return 0;}
```

эта программа должна считывать строку введенную пользователем и заменять в ней слова (которыетоже вводит пользователь)

файл заголовка(Header.h)

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

Comment: Функция `strncpy` в общем случае не выполняет завершение строки нулевым символом. Также, почему у вас в коде постоянно объявляются какие-то локальные переменные, которые нигде никак не используются? И вообще, на каком языке это написано? Почему на вопросе одновременно стоят теги [C] и [C++]?

Comment: спасибо за подсказку с strncpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша программа выглядит как-то... странно! Ну да ладно. По сути вопроса:

Для того, что бы найти место "падения" программы поступаем следующим образом:

1. Перекомпилируем программу с ключом -g - как-то так: *gcc -g main.c*
2. Запускаем отладчик *gdb*
3. Отладчику командуем загрузить программу *file a.out*
4. Запускаем программу под отладачиком *run*
5. Отладчик укажет место падения.

В Вашем случае, это строка

```
char ll = m[k];
```

Падение происходит потому, что переменная *k* имсеет недопустимое значение 5840. А вот почему у неё такое безумное значение - разбираться Вам.

Подозреваю, что из-за того, что условие

```
if (ll == yy && at > 0 && t <= strlen(pot)) {
    hh = hh + 1;
    at = at + 1;
    t = t++;
    //ms[hh] = ll;
}
```

не срабатывает и переменная *t* сохраняет нулевое значение.

Comment: Спасибо, дело похоже и правда в этом выражении(когда я комментиирую "at > 0 &&" ошибки не происходит)